# Send response to EventSource after webook (Flask + uWSGI + nginx)

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi, webhooks, eventsource

I have Flask application with route (webhook) receiving POST requests (webhooks) from external phone application (incomming call = POST request). This route sets threading.Event.set() and based on this event, another route (eventsource) sends an event stream to opened EventSource connection on a webpage created by yet another route (eventstream).

```
telfa_called = Event()
telfa_called.clear()
call = ""

@telfa.route('/webhook', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def webhook():
    global call
    print('THE CALL IS HERE')
    x = request.data
    y = ET.fromstring(x.decode())
    caller_number = y.find('caller_number').text
    telfa_called.set() #  setting threading.Event for another route
    return Response(status=200)

@telfa.route('/eventstream', methods = ['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def eventstream():
    jsid = str(uuid.uuid4())
    return render_template('telfa/stream.html', jsid=jsid)

def eventsource_gen():
    while 1:
        if telfa_called.wait(10):
            telfa_called.clear()
            print('JE TO TADY')
            yield "data: {}\n\n".format(json.dumps(call))

@telfa.route('/eventsource', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def eventsource():
    return Response(eventsource_gen(), mimetype='text/event-stream')`
```

Everything works great when testing in pure Python application. The problem starts, when I move this to production server, where I use uWSGI with nginx. (Other parts of this Python application work without any troubles.)

When the eventSource connection is opened and incomming webhook should be processed, whole flask server stucks (for all other users, too), page stops to load and I cannot find, where the error is.
I only know, the POST request from external application is received, but the response to EventSource is not made. 
I suspect it has something to do with processes - the EventSource connection from JavaScript is one process, the webhook route another - and they do not communicate. So or so, I suppose this has to have very trivial solution, but I didn't find it in past 3 days and nights. Any hints, please? Thanks in advance.

To be complete, this my uwsgi config file:

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app
enable-threads = true
master = true
processes = 5
threads = 2
uid = www-data
gid= www-data
socket = /tmp/myproject.sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
limit-as=512
buffer-size = 512000
workers = 5
max-requests = 100
req-logger = file:/tmp/uwsg-req.log
logger = file:/tmp/uwsgi.log`
```